# xhttp.send returning 404 not found but file exist

Tags: php, ajax, get, xmlhttprequest

please look at the picture, I'm calling same function in two page.

when I call function within the page opened without any parameter, status code is `200` and I get result `correctly`.

but when I call function within the page opened with GET parameter, status code is `404` and I get error "`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`"

my function is:

```
function myajax(method, api, data, callback){

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.open(method, api, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        callback(this.responseText);
    }
};

xhttp.send(data);
}
```

and call that with:

```
myajax("POST", "../wp-content/themes/ad/config.php", "data="+data+"&api="+myapi, myCallBack);
```

[image: my image]

Comment: Show reponse and request headers.

Comment: I know nothing about Wordpress, so this is just an idea: are you sure Wordpress accepts those kind of parameters? E.g. maybe it requires pretty URLs with slashes (/data/value/api/value/) or just (/dataValue/apiValue/) instead of the typical parameters with the question mark and ampersand.

Comment: Yes, it accepted, however, I changed the apiValue precisely, but my problem was not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was a lengthy data payload. Whenever the data to be sent is goes beyond the size of packets received in the config.php file, this file will not respond to request and the client receives a response with a `404` header.